# How to fill cell with favorite colors on single click?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors

I would like to quickly manually mark some cells of interest by changing their background to:

- light red
- light green
- light grey

In old versions of Excel, this was easy: it was possible to detach the palette into separate tool window

[image]

and when target cells were selected, clicking desired color did the job. In recent Excel versions, I am unable to make the palette always visible so I always need clicking two different places when changing the color: 1 – open palette; 2 – select color.

**Is there any way to pick from more colors on single click as before?**

*When finishing writing this question, I found one way and added it as answer but feel free to propose more efficient way, if you know it.*

Answer (score 0):

I found a way which requires some preparation, but then it works on single click.

### Use cell styles

Preparation:
In **Home** tab, add styles for desired fill colors (follow yellow marking on image below).

Usage:
Added styles are available on single click (see red marking on image below).

[image]

- The **Styles** palette automatically expands to all available space in **Home** toolbar. The larger screen resolution is available, the more styles is reachable on single click.
- On clicking the style, all groups of properties checked in **Style** window (also visible above) are applied to the cell. This allows to combine multiple styles applied to a cell if they do not overlap. To quickly revert to defaults, select **Normal** style.
- Styles can be imported from another workbook using **Merge Styles** command accessible from bottom right button of the palette.